# qt project compile error cannot find -lGL

Tags: 14.04, qt5

I tried to compile Qt(5.3.1) example project but the following error comes up

> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL

What does it mean. This error doesn't come up when I compile it in Windows. So How do I fix it?

Comment: you are missing libGL
-l to gcc means to include the library GL is the library's base name

Comment: You mean to include in the source code. But this is an example project distributed with Qt installation. Can you explain a bit. Should I install additional libraries?

Comment: What they said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use library in the program you build, you must have the "dev" version of library, as well as connect it to your application (already done in examples) 
You need to install "dev" version by

```
apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev
```